# Why can't we use parenthesis to call a wrapper function in Python decorators?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, decorator, python-decorators

I am learning about decorators in Python:

```
def f1(func):
    def wrapper():
        print('Start')
        func()
        print('End')
    return wrapper

@f1
def f():
    print('Learn Decorators')

f()
```

In this example , I can't understand why we are returning wrapper like this : return wrapper
and not: return wrapper()

Comment: Because `wrapper()` would _run_ the function, instead of returning the function.